# postgres query aggregate function does not display the null values

Tags: postgresql

I have this table

```
id | present
------------
A | false
B | null
C | null
D | false
E | false
```

and perform this query

```
SELECT array_agg(id)
FROM above_table
WHERE present IS NULL
```

I expect this to return a single row of

```
B C
```

But instead I get an empty row.

If I do

```
SELECT array_agg(id)
FROM above_table
WHERE present = 'false'
```

I get a row of

```
A D E
```

Any thoughts on why `IS NULL` does not return the array?

Comment: I believe so. The present column is `boolean`

Comment: What do you get for `\d above_table` in psql?

Comment: Column     |              Type              |       Modifiers
----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------
 present       | boolean                        |

Comment: @aubonphysics any update to your question?

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your table definition or your test.

If you define column `present` as boolean and the rows with id B and C really are NULL, then your first query will give what you are expecting.

My console log:

```
strobel=# create table quest (id character, present boolean);
CREATE TABLE
strobel=# insert into quest values ('A',false);
INSERT 0 1
strobel=# insert into quest values ('D',false);
INSERT 0 1
strobel=# insert into quest values ('E',false);
INSERT 0 1
strobel=# insert into quest(id) values ('B');
INSERT 0 1
strobel=# insert into quest(id) values ('C');
INSERT 0 1
strobel=# select * from quest order by 1;
 id | present 
----+---------
 A  | f
 B  | 
 C  | 
 D  | f
 E  | f
(5 Zeilen)

strobel=# SELECT array_agg(id) FROM quest WHERE present IS NULL;
 array_agg                                                            
-----------
 {B,C}
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: This is what I see in the database. But I don't get the results back. I get an empty array.

Comment: I can confirm this correct expected behave. Maybe your NULL is not NULLs. Try to set format for NULLs by `\pset null '[*** NULL ***]'`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0995c/1) for me

#### DDL

```
CREATE TABLE above_table
    ("id" varchar(1), "present" boolean)
;
```

#### DML

```
INSERT INTO above_table
    ("id", "present")
VALUES
    ('A', false),
    ('B', NULL),
    ('C', NULL),
    ('D', false),
    ('E', false)
;
```

#### DQL

```
SELECT array_agg(id)
FROM   above_table
WHERE  present IS NULL;
```

#### Output

```
array_agg
B,C
```

---

I suspect something else is happening.  Have you considered that the same table name may be used in multiple schemas and that you are pulling from the correct schema?

Comment: I have not considered that. Looking into it.

Comment: @aubonphysics The same thing I did. Everything okay. You *have to check your table*. Or you are in the wrong database. Or ...

Comment: @Str. I believe his comment is in response to my last statement regarding the schema, not the table/query stuff.